# R HighChart Legend

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, highmaps

Now, I use the package named `highcharter[2]` of R to draw some charts.
I have drawn the chart like this

[image]

As we can see, the legend is default use the range to represents the color, 
      such as range from 0 to 50 represents green.I want to change the legend value.

Use String like good to represents the range from 0 to 50, and so on. 
      I want to know how to change the legend labels in R.I have tried use JavaScript,
      but I don't know how to call the rollback function, I have seen that It
      has the attribute `labelformat[3]`, But I can't understand the usage, Is anybody can help me?  Thank you!

> [2]:R package
>
> [3]attribute

Comment: Can you provide some sample code please

Comment: Have you seen http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highmaps.html and www.highcharts.com/maps/demo, right? Which example fit your needs?